# dired-do-delete fails to delete file

Tags: dired, debugging

In Dired, with point on a file name, I invoke `dired-do-delete` and confirm. The line disappears, as it normally does when a file is deleted. But the file is not in fact deleted, as I can see by e.g. opening the relevant folder with MacOS Finder or refreshing the Dired buffer (which causes the line to reappear). No error is emitted (so `toggle-debug-on-error` doesn't help), and the problem occurs only sometimes and for no apparent reason, so I'm finding it hard to diagnose. I include output from profiler, in case it allows others to identify possible causes.

```
      2,135,063  98% - command-execute
      2,135,063  98%  - funcall-interactively
      1,294,448  59%   - dired-do-delete
      1,292,160  59%    - dired-internal-do-deletions
      1,292,160  59%     - apply
      1,292,160  59%      - all-the-icons-dired--refresh-advice
      1,262,479  58%       - #<subr dired-internal-do-deletions>
      1,197,929  55%        - dired-mark-pop-up
      1,197,929  55%         - yes-or-no-p
        142,618   6%          - read-from-minibuffer
         10,160   0%           - redisplay_internal (C function)
          8,480   0%            - eval
          8,184   0%               doom-modeline-segment--debug
            168   0%               doom-modeline-segment--window-number
             32   0%             - doom-modeline-format--main
             16   0%              - format-mode-line
             16   0%               - eval
             16   0%                  doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
             32   0%               doom-modeline-segment--buffer-position
             32   0%               doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
             32   0%             - doom-modeline-format--project
             16   0%              - format-mode-line
             16   0%               - eval
             16   0%                  doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
          1,680   0%              menu-bar-update-buffers
          1,504   0%             mu4e~proc-filter
            620   0%           - minibuffer-inactive-mode
            620   0%            - run-mode-hooks
            620   0%               run-hooks
            310   0%           - minibuffer-mode
            310   0%            - run-mode-hooks
            310   0%               run-hooks
            168   0%           - gcmh-register-idle-gc
            168   0%            - run-with-timer
            168   0%             - run-at-time
            120   0%              - timer-activate
            120   0%                 timer--activate
             24   0%                timer-set-time
             96   0%           - undo-auto--undoable-change
             96   0%            - undo-auto--boundary-ensure-timer
             96   0%             - run-at-time
             72   0%              - timer-activate
             72   0%                 timer--activate
             24   0%                timer-set-time
             16   0%             command-execute
         58,261   2%        - dired-delete-file
         58,261   2%         - delete-file
         58,261   2%          - apply
         55,189   2%           - #<subr delete-file>
         55,189   2%            - move-file-to-trash
         55,189   2%             - system-move-file-to-trash
         55,189   2%              - shell-command
         55,189   2%               - apply
         55,189   2%                - shell-command--shell-command-with-editor-mode
         54,165   2%                 - #<subr shell-command>
         54,165   2%                  - shell-command-on-region
         14,336   0%                   - format-insert-file
         14,336   0%                    - set-auto-coding
         14,336   0%                       find-auto-coding
         10,278   0%                     #<compiled -0x14fd729686068967>
          7,168   0%                   - delete-file
          7,168   0%                    - apply
          7,168   0%                     - org-roam-db-autosync--delete-file-a
          5,120   0%                        org-roam-file-p
            604   0%                   - fundamental-mode
            604   0%                    - run-mode-hooks
            604   0%                     - run-hooks
            294   0%                      - yas-global-mode-enable-in-buffers
            294   0%                       - yas-minor-mode-on
            294   0%                          yas-minor-mode
          3,072   0%           - org-roam-db-autosync--delete-file-a
          1,024   0%              org-roam-file-p
          3,312   0%        - dired-fun-in-all-buffers
          2,288   0%         - dired-delete-entry
          2,288   0%          - dired-remove-entry
          2,288   0%           - dired-goto-file
          2,288   0%            - dired-goto-file-1
          1,024   0%               dired-switches-escape-p
            240   0%             - dired-get-filename
            240   0%              - dired-current-directory
            240   0%               - dired-subtree--get-ov
            240   0%                  dired-subtree--get-all-ovs-at-point
          1,024   0%           dired-buffers-for-dir
          1,024   0%          mapcar
            494   0%        - progress-reporter-done
            494   0%           apply
            309   0%        - make-progress-reporter
            309   0%         - progress-reporter-do-update
            309   0%            apply
         21,497   0%       - all-the-icons-dired--refresh
         12,744   0%        - dired-get-filename
          8,184   0%           dired-switches-escape-p
          4,560   0%         - dired-current-directory
          4,560   0%          - dired-subtree--get-ov
          4,560   0%             dired-subtree--get-all-ovs-at-point
            400   0%          all-the-icons-dired--remove-all-overlays
          1,264   0%    - dired-get-filename
          1,024   0%       dired-switches-escape-p
            240   0%     - dired-current-directory
            240   0%      - dired-subtree--get-ov
            240   0%         dired-subtree--get-all-ovs-at-point
        838,711  38%   - ps/profiler-toggle
        838,711  38%    - if
          1,287   0%     - profiler-start
          1,287   0%        apply
            880   0%   - dired-previous-line
            880   0%    - dired-next-line
            880   0%     - line-move
            320   0%      - line-move-1
            320   0%       - #<compiled 0x1054ea3f9d096532>
            320   0%          line-move-finish
         21,436   0% - redisplay_internal (C function)
         16,388   0%  - jit-lock-function
         16,388   0%   - jit-lock-fontify-now
         16,388   0%    - jit-lock--run-functions
         16,388   0%     - #<compiled 0x1fe4443f05ec5afe>
         16,388   0%      - font-lock-fontify-region
         16,388   0%         font-lock-default-fontify-region
          2,344   0%  - eval
          2,048   0%     doom-modeline-segment--buffer-default-directory
            168   0%     doom-modeline-segment--window-number
             32   0%   - doom-modeline-format--main
             16   0%    - format-mode-line
             16   0%     - eval
             16   0%        doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
             32   0%     doom-modeline-segment--buffer-position
             32   0%     doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
             32   0%   - doom-modeline-format--project
             16   0%    - format-mode-line
             16   0%     - eval
             16   0%        doom-modeline-segment--major-mode
          1,680   0%    menu-bar-update-buffers
          1,024   0%    kill-this-buffer-enabled-p
          3,194   0% - timer-event-handler
          3,018   0%  - apply
          2,922   0%   - help-at-pt-maybe-display
          2,922   0%    - display-local-help
            860   0%       apply
             21   0%       substitute-command-keys
             96   0%   - blink-cursor-start
             96   0%    - blink-cursor--start-timer
             96   0%     - run-with-timer
             96   0%      - run-at-time
             48   0%         timer-set-time
             48   0%       - timer-activate
             48   0%          timer--activate
             80   0%    timer-inc-time
             72   0%  - timer-activate
             72   0%     timer--activate
            336   0% - gcmh-register-idle-gc
            336   0%  - run-with-timer
            336   0%   - run-at-time
            264   0%    - timer-activate
            264   0%       timer--activate
             72   0%      timer-set-time
              0   0%   ...
```

Comment: I'm on mac, plain emacs 27.1 and the method call stack looks quite different from your profiling stack. I would try to find what is the actual shell command is being run at system-move-file-to-trash. I would see if I could point that instead to to a wrapper shell script that logs the real delete shell command before calling it.

Comment: I'll post my questions as separate comments. First: does an immediate repeat attempt to delete the same file (always/sometimes) succeed or fail?

Comment: Second: when a deletion fails, has the copy-to-trash part of the operation succeeded?

Comment: Third: what happens if you set `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to `nil`?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. I'll provide answers next time the problem occurs (it may take days for that to happen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noticing that the problem never seemed to arise when `delete-by-moving-to-trash` was set to `nil`, I emptied the trash and re-set `delete-by-moving-to-trash` to `t`. The problem then only recurred when the trash became very big. So although I never managed to fully diagnose the issue, I considered this a solution given that it will make the problem disappear for several months, until the trash is emptied again.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen. Sounds like a bug in your Emacs version on the platform you're using.

If you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), the please consider filing a bug report, using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

If you don't see the same thing without your init file, then bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks. I would normally bisect the init file, but in this case the error occurs only sometimes, as noted, so that approach can't really help me isolate the cause of the problem.